# Nginx - Forwarding a request to the Server-App if 'alias' fails

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

For a project I implemented automatic serverside thumbnail-generation. If you request an Image with '_thumb' in its filename the server checks if there already is a thumbnail for the original image, if not it generates it and sends it back. Works fine.

Now I'd like to bring Nginx into the mix to serve the images directly from the harddrive without involving the server-app (the url itself would work fine and return the image if requested from the server-app itself).

The following Block works fine, if the thumbnail already exists. If there is no thumbnail already generated it just responds 404 - unsurprisingly.

**How would I modify the following Nginx-Block to make another request to the server in case the thumbnail cant be found to create it?**

Request

```
http://www.proj.com/files/images/234782348234/bunny_thumb.jpg
```

Nginx-Block

```
location ~* ^/files/images/(\w+)/.+_thumb\.(jpg|png|gif)$ {
   alias /srv/proj/data/uploads/images/temp/$1_thumb.$2;
   // No image found? Request it from the server directly on "files/images/234782348234/bunny_thumb.jpg"
}
```

Actual File-Path

```
/srv/proj/data/uploads/images/temp/234782348234_thumb.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally had to tackle it again and found a pretty easy solution. RegexMatches stillt won't work in try_files. So I just used "alias" to direct to the actual file-path and defined a 'error_page 404' pointing to the expressapp:

```
location ~* ^/files/images/(\w+)/.+_thumb\.(jpg|png|gif)$ {
   error_page 404 @makethumb
   alias /srv/proj/data/uploads/images/temp/$1_thumb.$2;
 }

location @makethumb {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000$uri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to read the excellent blog of the nginx company.

What you search for is called named location with try_files.

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-web-server/

https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @backend;
}

location @backend {
    proxy_pass http://backend.example.com;
}
```

For your case I would try the following

```
location ~* ^/files/images/(\w+)/.+_thumb\.(jpg|png|gif)$ {
   try_files /srv/proj/data/uploads/images/temp/$1_thumb.$2 @callapp;
   // No image found? Request it from the server directly
   // on "files/images/234782348234/bunny_thumb.jpg"
}

location @callapp {
...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the fallback works great. Thumbnails now are generated and send back. Only issue: nginx doesn‘t find the generated thumbnail and always falls back to @callapp. Is something wrong with the try_files line? Definitely possible to use $1/$2 in a try_files line?

Comment: maybe you will need to but a `{}` around the numbers `/srv/proj/data/uploads/images/temp/${1}_thumb.$2` but I'm not sure

Comment: Nope, thats not it. If I use {} the Nginx-Check says "unknown variable "1". So, whats wrong here?

Comment: Can you run for your IP the debug log ? http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html